# Adjective or Noun?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

In the following sentence

> The term Orwellian has evolved into a descriptive of totalitarian and authoritarian practices.

Is the word 'descriptive' a noun or an adjective? Now it is my understanding that practices is a noun and hence descriptive should be an adjective describing that noun but still, there is a bit of confusion especially when this sentence has been written in a different manner in some places like below.

> Orwell’s work continues to influence popular and political culture,
>   and the term Orwellian – descriptive of totalitarian or authoritarian
>   social practices – has entered the language together with many of his
>   neologisms, including Big Brother, Thought Police, Room 101, memory
>   hole, newspeak, doublethink, proles, unperson, and thoughtcrime.

Comment: Where did you find that sentence? Or did you invent it?

Comment: The word 'descriptive' can be used either as an adjective or as a noun. Compare it to 'palliative' which can be an adjective (palliative care for the terminally sick) or as a noun (she gave him a palliative to relieve the pain).

Comment: @BillJ It is from the book 1984 by George Orwell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Morphologically it is an adjective, as you rightly say, but syntactically it is here used as a noun.

I guess it could be explained through ellipsis, ie there is an omitted *term*: *The term Orwellian has evolved into a descriptive **term** of totalitarian and authoritarian practices.* But then you have two *terms*, and so for stylistic reasons the second one has been left out.

So, you could still say that *descriptive* is an adjective, modifying the 'ghost' of the omitted noun *term*. As English is very flexible with its parts-of-speech, it's kind of both then, and that works fine, even if it seems a bit unusual.